# How to pass catch block statement another Activity?

Tags: android

How to pass catch block value to another Activity? My Activity work fine when access URL and get XML response when server is busy or not respond, How do I pass catch block statement to another Activity?

```
       public class AgAppHelperMethods
       {
         private static final String LOG_TAG = null;
         public static String varMobileNo;
         public static String varPinNo;
         String[][] xmlRespone = null;
         public static String[][] AgAppXMLParser( String parUrl)
         {
    String _node,_element;
            String[][] xmlRespone = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try
               {        
                String url = parUrl;
                URL finalUrl = new URL(url);    
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) finalUrl.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =  
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new  
                    InputSource(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                NodeList list=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
            _node=new String();
            _element = new String();
            xmlRespone = new String[list.getLength()][2];
            for (int i=0;i<list.getLength();i++)
                {
                    Node value=list.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0);
                    _node=list.item(i).getNodeName();
                    _element=value.getNodeValue();
                    xmlRespone[i][0] = _node;
                    xmlRespone[i][1] = _element;

                }//end for

            urlConnection.disconnect();

        }//end try

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "CONNECTION ERROR O SERVER NOT RESPONDING", e);
    } 
    return xmlRespone;         

}
```

Comment: See the "how to pass XXXXXXXX to another activity" in related questions

Comment: What do you mean by " catch block statement" ? What are you expecting to pass?

Comment: but i do not wnt to use intent my class is not activity

Comment: if invalir ur its show message SERVER NOT RESPONDING"   how i pass exception to another actiovity

Comment: How to pass catch block value to another activity? your qestion contain this. But you said in comment your class is not an activity????????

Comment: yes my class is not activity so how i pass its exception value to another activity??

Answer (score 2):

As you said you do not want to call any intent and u do not pas this exception to any specific class so cant use Actitvity...

Then  How about this?

```
Public Class Messages{

static String message = "";

public static void setMessage(String msg){
        message= msg;

    }
public static String getMessage(){
   return message;

}



}
```

............... here you set it

```
    catch(Exception e)

{
  Messages.setmessage("CONNECTION ERROR O SERVER NOT RESPONDING");
}
```

And u can get it anywhere like,

String message = Messages.getMessage();

it returns latest updated message or empty string.. if you want to keep all the message then you can use a array..will it work for you?

Comment: this line hsow error

Messages.setmessage("error"+e.getMessage);

Comment: now is fixed byt this          Messages.setMessage("error"+e.getMessage());

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use Intent if you need to pass to some other Activity.

A simple solution would be to pass the Context of your Calling Activity thorugh the Constructor of the helper class. And from there make use of the Context Object to start a new Activity.

Something like this,

```
catch(Exception e)

{
   Intent i=new Intent(contextObj,ActitvityName.class);
    contextObj.startActivity(i);

}
```

And if you need to pass the Exception use the putExtra of your Intent like this,

```
 i.putExtra("exception",e.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

And in the called Activity get the value using the bundle object.

Comment: The Context Object of your Activity. You have to pass it from your Activity when you initialize this helper class. I hope you know how to create constructors.

Comment: i do not pas this exception to any specific class so cant  use ActitvityName.class   becuase is only function class which use http to gget xml response somany other classes use this class so i cant sent only specific vlass this result value so how do i  set  exception value to globally access any other classs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive the Exception in other class from which you are calling the method then you can do it by following.

1. Remove catch block which you want to receive in another class
2. Throw the Exception from the method by adding a *throws Exception/IoException* at the end of the method
3. Now from the calling class of the method put the try and catch block and handle the Exception over there.

   **Edit**

If you want to pass the exception to any other class other than the calling of the method class, you can create a class for the exception and using the getter and setter methods you can set and get exception from every where, just you need to pass that class object to the receiving exception class.

Comment: Try it out yourself. This is not a site for give you examples. I can just explain you. the rest thing you should do yourself.